# How to make a radian argument still get interpreted in radian when working with \psplot in PostScript form?

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

When using `\psplot` in PS form (or `algebraic=false`) the interval must be specified in degrees. However, sometimes, I need `algebraic=false` but interval is given in radian. Is it possible to achieve this scenario?

The following code shows that the output of plotting `r=2^(x/2)` (radius as a function of angle `x`) with `algebraic=false` and `algebraic=true` are different because PSTricks assumes that interval in first case is in degrees.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\psset{polarplot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-3,-3)(3,3)
    \psplot{2 Pi mul neg}{2 Pi mul}{2 x  10 div exp}
\end{pspicture}\qquad
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-3,-3)(3,3)
    \psplot[algebraic]{2 Pi mul neg}{2 Pi mul}{2^(x/10)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How to make a radian argument still get interpreted in radian when working with `\psplot` in PostScript form?

Comment: The file `pst-plot.tex` contains a line `F@pstplot x \ifPst@algebraic RadtoDeg \fi PtoC`, so this conversion for `algebraic=true` is fixed. Bug or feature, this may be answered by @Herbert.

Comment: @Christoph: I think it is a bug because the code writers did not anticipate the case in which the interval can represent not only angle but also non-angle.

Comment: if f(x) is in PS notation then we have x1 and x2 also in PS notation and that is degrees!

Comment: @Herbert: Then this feature will not allow  `\psplot[polarplot]{<RPN>}{<RPN>}{<RPN>}` to plot a graph of `r=f(t)=a^t` for example.

Comment: your first example shows exactly this case!

Comment: @Herbert: So  the conclusion is that it is impossible to plot the *correct* `r(t)=a^t` in `algebraic=false,polarplot=true`, right?

Comment: ??? your plot shows _exactly_ the polarplot from -6.28 to +6.29 DEGREES!

Comment: if you want f(x) still in radiant then use `{2 x DegtoRad 10 div exp}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will be the same with the correct syntax!

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\psset{polarplot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-3,-3)(3,3)
    \psplot{2 Pi mul neg RadtoDeg }{2 Pi mul RadtoDeg}{2 x DegtoRad 10 div exp}
\end{pspicture}\qquad
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-3,-3)(3,3)
    \psplot[algebraic]{2 Pi mul neg}{2 Pi mul}{2^(x/10)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is wrong?? `(Pi,2^(Pi/10)` is `(3.14,1.2)`

Comment: OK. I was wrong. The point cannot be represented in RPN-Infix syntax because the function represents `r` value rather than `y`.